# Spring container is looking at wrong path while loading multiple spring configuration files

Tags: spring

We are using Spring framework in the project. I am loading `applicationContext` file from web.xml in the following way:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/CustomerService/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I am trying to load one configuration file `JobDesigner-springintegration.xml` inside the `applicationContext` file in the following way:

```
  <import resource="JobDesigner-springintegration.xml"/>
```

Now, I am trying to load few more configuration files inside the

```
`JobDesigner-springintegration.xml`  file in the following manner:

<import resource="*.xml"/>
```

But weirdly the spring container is looking in a wrong path something like below:
 `jndi:/localhost/cciupg/WEB-INF/CustomerService/`
The log excerpts is shown below:

```
12:52:15,202 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:52:15,202 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/CustomerService/JobDesigner-springintegration.xml]
12:52:15,453 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:52:15,448 WARN  [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver] Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [jndi:/localhost/cciupg/WEB-INF/CustomerService/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system
java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [jndi:/localhost/cciupg/WEB-INF/CustomerService/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jndi:/localhost/cciupg/WEB-INF/CustomerService/
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:205)
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getFile(UrlResource.java:169)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:526)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(ServletContextResourcePatternResolver.java:92)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:347)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:279)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDe
```

The question here is why the spring container is looking at wrong path `jndi:/localhost/cciupg/WEB-INF/CustomerService/` instead of `/WEB-INF/CustomerService/`?

And the weird part is why it is appending `jndi:/localhost/cciupg` to the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WEB-INF is not part of the classpath I believe. Therefore it cannot find the your *.xml files. I believe jndi is likely the last location spring has checked when throwing the error after looking down the classpath.

In other words, try putting your files in the classpath. In java projects I usually see resources in the main -> resources path.